# Why is Windows seeing my NAS as two separate devices (one with FQDN, the other with local name)?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, server-message-block

- My home LAN has a Windows Active Directory domain, with the DNS name `corp.example.com`.
- My Synology NAS has the FQDN `nas.corp.example.com.`.
- My Windows 10 desktop has the FQDN `cube.corp.example.com.`.
- I am using split-brain DNS:

  - The DNS servers within my home LAN will report that `nas.corp.example.com` is `172.16.1.10`.
  - The Internet-accessible public DNS server for `example.com` will return `A IN 2.718.281.828` for queries for both `nas.corp.example.com` and `corp.example.com` - where `2.718.281.828` is my home router's public IPv4 address (I use port forwarding, ofc).
- Both my (Windows 10) desktop computer and Synology NAS are domain-joined.

  - Running `ipconfig /all` on my desktop reports `Primary Dns Suffix: corp.example.com`.
- Therefore I expect Windows 10 to know that `nas.corp.example.com.` (FQDN) **and** `nas` (single-label) are the same host.
- But Windows 10 File Explorer lists my NAS twice: first with the FQDN and again with the single-label name.
- Answer me these questions three:

  - Why is it doing this?
  - Is this benign, or does it cause issues (e.g. extraneous lookup requests, too many connections, SMB issues?)
  - How can I make it coalesce the two nodes into one?

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: What is a DC (OS, version)? What is domain level? How is WINS configured in the domain?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov The DC is Windows Server 2012 R2. The forest and domain functioning levels are both 2012 R2. There are no WINS servers in the domain (at least that I know of).